# Retrofit Unable to create call adapter

Tags: android, retrofit2

I followed the format from the tutorial in inserting data to database using Retrofit Library. The logcat shows the error `Unable to create call adapter for retrofit2.Call<dagger.com.japorms.model.User_Account_Model> for method APIService.registerUser`

Here is my APIService Interface:

```
    public interface APIService {


    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("test_db/register.php")
    Call<User_Account_Model> registerUser(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);
}
```

Here is the Method:

```
 public void registerUser(){
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Registering Account");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait ...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.73:8080/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();



    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    User_Account_Model user_account_model = new User_Account_Model();
    user_account_model.email = reg_email_et.getText().toString();
    user_account_model.password = reg_pass_et.getText().toString();

    String conf_pass = reg_conf_pass_et.getText().toString();

    if(user_account_model.password.equals(conf_pass)){

        Call<User_Account_Model> call = service.registerUser(user_account_model.email,user_account_model.password);
        call.enqueue((new Callback<User_Account_Model>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User_Account_Model> call, Response<User_Account_Model> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User_Account_Model> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        builder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>REGISTER FAILED</font>")).setMessage("password and confirm password did not match")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("Ok", null).create().show();
    }


}
```

my format is the same as the tutorial except I have 2 parameters. I hope you could help me explain this logcat because I'm having a hard time understanding it since I'm new to this Retrofit library. Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you paste User_Account_Model.class here

Have you add in app gradle file

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
```

Comment: public class User_Account_Model {

    public String email;
    public String password;
}

Comment: have u added this compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'

Comment: I was using the older version. I changed the version to 2.2.0 and now it works. Thanks man!